# How can i perform a smooth css transition to my sticky bar?

Tags: jquery, css

I need to make this sticky bar, not just stick to top, but with CSS transition, I mean smoothly because it's kinda rough for now, any hints will do great !
This website contains the exact animation I want https://css-tricks.com/

This is the CSS code

```
#bar {  
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    max-height:50px;
    background-color: #595959;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
}
.bar-fixed {
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the jQuery that performs the class adding

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        console.log($(window).scrollTop());
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 59) {
            $('#bar').addClass('bar-fixed');
        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < 60) {
            $('#bar').removeClass('bar-fixed');
        }
     });
});
```

I can provide the HTML if needed...
I tried to do this with a CSS transition this way, but it didn't work,and it is logic, because class isn't a property,so I think it can be done with jQuery, but I'm not sure.a tutorial or course, will be great, so I can pick and learn my own choices, thank you.

Comment: Please learn how to format your post(s)

Comment: You should add your HTML here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/zket24av/
**CSS**

```
#bar {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    max-height:50px;
    background-color: #595959;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
}
.bar-fixed {
    top:-100px;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elBar=$('#bar');
  var elBarTop=elBar.offset().top+elBar.outerHeight();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > elBarTop) {
        if (elBar.hasClass('bar-fixed')){
             if (!elBar.hasClass('scrolled')){
                elBar.addClass('scrolled');
                    elBar.stop(true).animate({'top':'0'},500);
             }
        } else {
            elBar.addClass('bar-fixed').css('top','-'+elBarTop+'px')
        }
        } else {
            elBar.stop(true).removeAttr('style').removeClass('scrolled bar-fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this is a nice example,but is a bit buggy tho,i will try to fix it,and upload w clean one

Comment: what do you mean with buggy?

Comment: The scrolling downward works fine,but when i go back to scrolling to top,when i reach the initial position where the bar should stop following,it disappears,and the top fixed one appears.
what should be happening,is when i scroll back to top,the recently appeared bar,should stick to that position,not disappear,and make place for the fixed one,did you get the point?or should i provide a demo?

Comment: This is the solution to the buggy animation you proposed,but it was generally very helpful 
'  $(document).ready(function() {
    var elBar=$('#bar');
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
            elBar.addClass('bar-fixed').animate({'top':'0'},1000)
        } else if ($(window).scrollTop()<60){
            elBar.removeClass('bar-fixed').animate({'top':'50'},0);
            elBar.clearQueue().stop().removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
});'
i added the if that checks if we reached the actual position of the bar,if true,the class is removed instantly

Comment: @ Vixed i don't seem to understand what does this code's actual role ?
' elBar.clearQueue().stop().removeAttr('style') ' could you explain?

Comment: I've changed it check at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/14deqtb3/
Let me know if you want me to update my answer with this version you don't need to put a number in your control { if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) }

Comment: the animation is still buggy,try my jquery instead,it is here,it works fine :(https://jsfiddle.net/14deqtb3/2/) 
And please explain the code : ' elBar.clearQueue().stop().removeAttr('style') '

Comment: But if my prev code helped you why do you removed the flag on the answer? **[clearQueque](https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/)** and **[stop](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)** you can also use **.stop(true)** instead of **.clearQueue().stop()**

Comment: because you still didn't explain the utility of the .clearQueue().stop() which can be replaced by .stop(true) ....now that you did,i thank you,you were helpful

Comment: sorry ;) another think I made I to stop recalling an animation each time user scroll with the class scrolled. check it! Nou you can have a Dynamic header and a fastest function https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/zket24av/

Comment: i see what you did,but it is more complicated,and also still buggy,just try the demo i posted in my comment,you still are not checking the scroll,when the user scrolls from the bottom to the top,so the animation goes smoothly,that is essential

Answer (score 0):

You need a transition!

```
$('#bar').addClass('bar-fixed').slideDown();

$('#bar').removeClass('bar-fixed').slideUp();
```

Comment: would you explain a bit more why we need a transaction?

Comment: The transition `slideDown()` I added gives the slide down effect that you see on the website you linked as your desired output for the fixed bar. Without it, it would just appear and disappear abruptly.

Comment: @ChrisGleason yes it does give that effect,but the problem is,it gives it only once after the page is loaded,is a bit buggy,but it is something like that,is there any other transition effects you can recommand?,

Comment: yeah, that was a typo @SimonMᶜKenzie. The answer still needs to be edited with a better explanation. Why does it actually needs a transition. What is the part the op did not do that this will help solve?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier, no worries - I thought you might have misread the answer. It's self-explanatory that a transition of some sort is required, as the question asks _"How can i perform a smooth css transition"_. That means there's definitely no point in stating "you need a transition", and I agree that the answer requires more detail, as it's effectively a code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try animating with JQuery instead, and then also change the class so that it has `position: fixed`

```
$( "#bar" ).animate({top: "0", otherStyle: "option"}, "slow");
$(".bar-not-fixed").attr("class", "bar-fixed");
```

This way you are separating the animation and the code that keeps the bar at the top of the screen.

Check [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: i will check it out,hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Add a transition, but you will also want to hide the element first, in order for the transition to run.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        console.log($(window).scrollTop());
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 59) {
            $('#bar').addClass('bar-fixed').slideDown();
        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < 60) {
            $('#bar').removeClass('bar-fixed');
        }
     });
});
```

CSS:

```
#bar {  
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    max-height:50px;
    background-color: #595959;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
}
#bar.bar-fixed {
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this question is a little confusing, since css-tricks doesn't actually have a sticky nav.

But if your transition isn't smooth, it's likely because your taking the bar out of the document flow without replacing it. (which causes the page to jump upward.)

I would suggest using [StickyJs](http://stickyjs.com/), but if you want to code it yourself, you essentially just need to make an empty bar object that has 0 height when your bar isn't sticky and 50px height when the bar is sticky.

```
#bar-fake
{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    background-color: #595959;
}
    #bar-fake.active
    {
         height: 50px;
         max-height: 50px;
    }
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function () 
    {
        console.log($(window).scrollTop());
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 59) 
        {
            $('#bar').addClass('bar-fixed');
            $('#bar-fake').addClass('active');
        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < 60) 
        {
            $('#bar').removeClass('bar-fixed');
            $('#bar-fake').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well the css tricks does have a sticky bar,you just have to scroll down a bit

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following in your JQuery:

```
 $('#bar').wrap('<div class="bar-placeholder"></div>');

  $('.bar-placeholder').height($('#bar').outerHeight());
```

Super simple, See working example [CodePen](http://codepen.io/jacobg182/pen/MKKWgG)

Comment: the example doesn't work i couldn't understand the added value

Comment: Okay, I don't see what the issue is looks alright to me.

Comment: Your example has a sticky bar,fixed on top,my example has a sticky bar,that before 60 scroll is normal,after 60 scroll it becomes fixed to top,what i cant achieve,is the transition that makes it fixed to the top,in a smooth way,like the css tricks website.